# How to apply of Istighfar?

Tags: practical-islam, hadith-interpretation

The hadith,

> "O people, repent to Allah and seek His forgiveness, for I repent to Him a hundred times a day."
> (see for example in [Sahih Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim:2702b))

Is it repetitively saying 100 times like "astaghfirlLah, astaghfirlLah, astarghfirlLah x 100 times consecutively?

Or is it meant to be, 1 istighfar is like how you would seek an apology to a person? For eg. Hey John, im really sorry for the mistake i did (with genuine remorse in the heart) = 1 istighfar

Answer (score 1):

The hadith in question is one out of many which highly recommend performing istighfar (seeking forgiveness or repenting to Allah).

There are versions speaking about "a hundred of times", "hundred times" in one day, and "more than 70 times" and also "70 times" in a single sitting. This already means that the final amount of repetition isn't that what really matters.

The point is that first of all a Muslim must repent from a sin he committed and was aware of, if he really believes in Allah. As else his heart will harden and he could take a path of kufr (kufr in Arabic also means rejection).

On the other hand we may perform sins unknowingly or without intention or simply have doubt whether or not what we did was right ... therefore it makes sense to repent in any case as Allah knows best.

When the prophet () says that he performs repentance 70 times or a hundred of times this is a strong recommendation to repent and ask for forgiveness.
Because we know that our prophet Muhammad () was granted forgiveness, but not us, nevertheless he () performed it, either to be thankful as he informed us in another context in a hadith or to teach his ummah.
This doesn't necessarily means that we must sit and repeat 70...100 times astaghfirullah in one sitting, even if this is pretty fine and will be following the sunnah, but instead of idle talk, or listening to nonsense or music it would be better to use any free minute to remember Allah and this can be done for example by asking Allah for forgiveness, as first it will strengen our faith, keep us away from sins and gets us nearer to Allah just to name a few benefits.

To summarize:
Yes you can sit and perform istighfar as you stated, but it would be much better to use any free time to remember Allah, either for example by praising him or asking him for forgiveness as we don'Ät know how many "small" mistakes we perform each day.

Answer (score 0):

Aslamu Walaykum

The way to seek forgiveness is to say "astgfirullah" which means "Allah forgive me" ; there is a verse in the quran about this :

> “If any one does evil or wrongs his own soul but afterwards seeks God’s forgiveness, he will find God Oft-forgiving, Most Merciful”. [4:110]

To have your sins forgiven and your repentance be accepted ; three conditions are to be met as :

1- Not involving in any other sin

2- Having the sense of regret in one's heart.

3-Not getting in the sin again.

If any one condition is not fulfilled then his repentance is invalid.

There isn't really a specific amount of times you have to do it, you can do 30, 100 or any number of times; the more you do the better is it. Hope this helps :)